# Retrieving servers local time

Tags: javascript

I have run into an issue retrieving the 'local time' from my server. What i mean by local time is displayed below when i call 'timedatectl status'

```
  Local time: Sun 2018-05-27 14:45:37 EDT
  Universal time: Sun 2018-05-27 18:45:37 UTC
    Timezone: America/New_York (EDT, -0400)
 NTP enabled: yes
 NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
    DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
              Sun 2018-03-11 01:59:59 EST
              Sun 2018-03-11 03:00:00 EDT
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
              Sun 2018-11-04 01:59:59 EDT
              Sun 2018-11-04 01:00:00 EST
```

I am able to access the UTC value from my server however i would like to retrieve the Local Time value instead to reflect any system changes to the timezone in my app. Currently i am acquiring the server time by requesting the date in the response header but that doesn't help me if the timezone on the system changes. This is being done with javascript.

Comment: @Marged i'm not sure what you mean. I am already able to retrieve the UTC time from the server. My issue is that i want to retrieve the servers 'Local Time' as it is displayed above.

Comment: Why not send localtime in the same / another header ?!? Show the source to the header part

Comment: @Marged I'm asking how that would be done? Calling getResponseHeader('Date') returns the UTC time. I'm not sure how to go about getting the Local Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who find themselves in this situation. I have an nginx webserver and came up with two solutions. One was to turn SSI on for nginx and echo the value that way, however i didn't think this would be the best course of action, so the second solution was to remove the timezone offset from the time which was being sent back by the server which was being converted by moment.js. This was the solution which fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
//get the current datetime
var weather1d=new Date();

// UTC & BST in my case
// UTC    Sun, 27 May 2018 20:01:28 GMT 
// Local  Sun May 27 2018 21:01:28 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)

 console.log('UTC ',weather1d.toUTCString());
 console.log('Local ',weather1d.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you, but instantiating weather1d with new Date() only displays the time based on whatever timezone the current users system is in. What i want to access is that local time value from the server, not the local system accessing the server.

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming you could run javascript with the above code on the server.

Comment: No problem. I think i found a solution to acquiring the data i need through the use of the SSI module in nginx. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need some serverside technique for this.

Depending on your infrastructure which you didn't convey you can use a reverse proxy which you establish in front of your webserver or you add the header at the webserver directly (server side includes, lua, ...)
Or you add the header in your application server, if you run NodeJS you can use JavaScript for this.